# In Excel, how do I make a stacked bar graph with 2 bar that have different data points?

Tags: excel

So I have the following data:

[image: Data]

I made 2 stacked bars with these data, notice both bar have different data points, my question is, how do I merge them to the same graph so I can compare them?

[image: Chart 1]
[image: Chart 2]

I would like something to look like this, is it possible?:

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have all 7 columns in your data table, and then fill in 0's for the values that don't apply to one row or the other.