# Excel: How do I make 4 different columns with stacked values on the same graph?

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns (Columns A and C) that I want to create with 3 different parts of data (Parts 1, 2, and 3) in them. This leads me to believe they should be stacked columns. I also have two columns D and B, that take just one column of values from the chart. So I want to have 4 columns/bars/categories in total on the graph. How can I manipulate this graph to make it this way? I'm fairly new to Excel, but just for a note, I'm using Pivot Tables. I would also like to maintain the Quarters and Months that they are in.

[image: Excel Chart and Spreadsheet]
Already checked this question, wasn't very helpful: [In Excel, how do I make a stacked bar graph with 2 bar that have different data points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056758/in-excel-how-do-i-make-a-stacked-bar-graph-with-2-bar-that-have-different-data)

This question suggests that I might not be able to do it, but I feel like I have seen it done before: [How can I create a graph in excel that uses multiple columns and does stacked columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957458/how-can-i-create-a-graph-in-excel-that-uses-multiple-columns-and-does-stacked-co)

This question is really helpful, but I would like to also show the different colors in the bar. Not just make it one color for a sum: [Combining Column Values in an Excel Pivot Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336509/combining-column-values-in-an-excel-pivot-table?rq=1)

Let me know if I should provide any further information or ways I need to improve this question. I'll be happy for any help. Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need a bar for column A (3 parts stacked), next to it a bar for column B (one part), next to it a bar for column C (3 parts) and next to it column D (one part), and all of these split by quarters, so 4 bars for each quarter?

Comment: Yes! And ideally split for each month as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll give it a try. It would be perfect if you could add a sketch of how you want it to look like (in Paint, or just pen-and-paper), and some sample data for the graph would also be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found a more or less simple solution, but it will require you to build a different pivot table. All your data will need to be grouped by Columns and Parts (for columns B and D it will always be Part 1, for columns A and C it will be parts 1-3). My randomly generated source data looks something like this: 
 [image]

Based on this source data build your pivot table with the following fields: Dates and Columns are the pivot rows, Parts are the columns, and Values are whatever you had in the values (Number in my case). Make sure to expand all selections on the pivot table for the chart to look right. the pivot will look something like this: 
[image][image]

Finally, select any cell in the pivot table, go to Insert tab and select a stacked chart. It will produce the 4 bars you need per each month and quarter, but the disadvantage is you will have the same colors for the same part in all columns (e.g. your Part 1 will be blue in all columns A-D). You can manually override it for each individual bar if you like.

[image]